# How do I invert a 64-bit variable in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I am trying to invert a 64-bit variable in verilog, but for some reason only one bit is inverted.

```
wire [63:0] bc;
assign bc = 64'b0;
assign notbc = ~bc;
```

I'm expecting the output to 64 bits of one's, but instead I get the most significant bit to be 1 and the others are 0's.
I also tried something else I found online:

```
assign notbc = bc ^ 64'b1;
```

but what I get this time is that the least significant bit is one and the others are 0's. What can I do to get the negation of every bit i.e. 64 bits of 1's?
Note: I'm limited to Verilog, I can't use SystemVerilog.

Here is the full module:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module notting(
output [63:0] out);

wire [63:0] bc;
assign bc = 64'b0;
assign out = ~bc;

endmodule
```

Comment: Your code works for me on 5 different platforms. https://www.edaplayground.com/x/CE6y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might just be missing from the code you pasted, but since `notbc` is not declared, it will be implicitly declared as a single-bit wire. With the following code you should be getting 64 ones, unless there is a problem with your simulator:

```
wire [63:0] bc, notbc;
assign bc = 64'b0;
assign notbc = ~bc;
```

Comment: notbc is declared as a 64-bit output, I just forgot to add it to the code snippet here. This means there must be a problem with the simulator?

Comment: Which simulator are you using? Honestly I would be surprised if there is a bug in the simulator with something as simple as this. Is it possible that you are driving the same signal from somewhere else? (e.g., a second assign statement?)

Comment: I'm using an online platform (cloudv.io).
I tried two things: assigning bc inside the module as in the pasted sample and also tried declaring it as an input and giving it the value of 0 (64 bits of 0's) in a testbench module. Both didn't work.

Comment: I went ahead and signed up for that service, and I am able to reproduce the issue you see. Like @dave_59, I also tested your code with several commercial simulators, where it works as expected, so I feel confident that this is a bug in their simulator. Which is rather worrying - I would not rely on a simulator with such a basic flaw. Interestingly, they also provide a synthesize option, which produces the following netlist implementation for your code: `assign out = 64'hffffffffffffffff;`

Answer (score -1):

I have checked your code in cloudv.io.
I have checked it works for small bitwidth
However, as I increased the bitwidth, the bug came out.
At this point I am not sure what causes the bug as I am not friendly with the system.
It seems like the bug can be reproduced when input is over fifty some bit wide.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).